# Bash shell scripting variables

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, variables

I have the following line in my shell script:

if [ -n "${USE_X:+1}" ]; then

I cannot figure out what the ":+1" part means. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html). That url provides the following explanation:

> **${parameter:+alt_value}**
>   If parameter set, use alt_value, else use null string.

and has the following example:

```
echo
echo "###### \${parameter:+alt_value} ########"
echo

a=${param4:+xyz}
echo "a = $a"      # a =

param5=
a=${param5:+xyz}
echo "a = $a"      # a =
# Different result from   a=${param5+xyz}

param6=123
a=${param6:+xyz}
echo "a = $a"      # a = xyz
```

Answer (score 4):

basically if $USE_X is set, the statement is evaluated to 1, otherwise null. Probably similar to

```
if [ -z $USE_X ];
then
    echo 1
else
    echo ""
fi
```

from http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PATTMATCHING :

```
${parameter+alt_value}, ${parameter:+alt_value}
If parameter set, use alt_value, else use null string.

Both forms nearly equivalent. The : makes a difference only when parameter has been declared and is null, see below.
```

Answer (score 2):

since aioobe already answered the question itself, here's a way to search a long manpage like Bash's using a regex, using this question as an example:

```
/\{.*:\+
```

The first forward-slash puts `less` (the manpage viewer) into search mode; the regex says to search for a left bracket, followed by any amount of stuff, then a colon followed by a plus sign. The bracket and plus need to be escaped because they have special meaning to the regex parser.